# CSS dynamic path next to text

Tags: css, sass

I have created a page with 3 sections that have title and a body. How can I create a line / path that goes next to the text line in the following picture:

[image]

The blue sections are space I left out with bootstrap with the idea that it should be used to put in the line. But since the body text is dinamic, the line/path has to be the height of the body.

What would be the best way to approach this ?

Here is the JSFiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/prozik/zvqn3be9/17/**

---

Here is how one section is structured in HTML:

```
<section class="about-three add-margin-bottom">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-sm-12 about-title">
      <div class="about-pre-sub"> Heading 3 </div>
      <h1> <span class="bold-text"> Title 3 </span> </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-sm-12 bg-primary"> 
      <!-- space for trace maybe -->  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-9 col-sm-12 about-sub">
      We gather a team of exceptional IT professionals to guide you through the process of project definition,
      design,
      development, testing and application.
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-12 bg-primary"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row small-padding-top">
    <div class="col-xl-11 col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xl-1 col-sm-12">
          <div class="about-one-logo"> logo </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-11 col-sm-12 about-one-details">
          It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when
          looking
          at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of
          letters,
          as
          opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop
          publishing
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-1 col-sm-12 bg-primary"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the line need to have curves?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. But if you have an idea with straight lines, I would like to see how :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the `add-margin-bottom` class and apply a `SVG` background inside the `.container::after` pseudoelement.

The `SVG` has 2 simple bezier curves (that you can adapt [as you prefer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)) and for each `2n` sections you need to rotate the Y-axis of the pseudoelement (so the background is flipped)

```
section:not(:last-of-type) .container::after {
    height: 230px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}

@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {

   .container::after {
      background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg viewBox="0 0 1200 250" 
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M 1190 0 S1190 125, 1065 125 H 125 S10 125, 10 250" 
                    stroke="%23007bff" stroke-width="10" fill="none"/></svg>') 
                    0 0 no-repeat;
    }

    section:nth-child(2n) .container::after {
       transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }  
}
```

---

note: I wrapped all the code in a mediaquery, since your blocks are visible when the viewport is at least `1200px` wide.

[JsFiddle Fork](https://jsfiddle.net/ng5f9zod/1/)

---

**Result**

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you master @Fabrizio Calderan! 
Mini added question: I've added `section:last-child` and `display: none`, so that the line doesn't appear at the last one. But it's still showing. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: probably your last section is not also the last child (in fact in the jsfiddle you have a sibling `script` element). Use `:last-of-type` instead (see my edit)

Comment: Thank you so much Fabrizio! I will look into my own, how to get the line inside the container also. The path outside work perfectly. Gotta google more how to make SVG in css.

Comment: basically you could wrap all the images in a container with position: relative and overlap a SVG with a vertical path in its ::after or ::before pseudolement which is absolutely positioned